# How would you implement pouchdb in a flutter app for android?

Tags: android, flutter, couchdb, database-replication, pouchdb

I need to use `pouchdb` in my flutter app, for replication with an existing `couchdb` server.
Since there is no native flutter package for `pouchdb` (or any couchdb implementation) that supports android, I'm considering using either a `webview` or a package like `flutter_js`, and running `pouchdb` in it.
I think this wouldn't be ideal in terms of performance, but the data would be rather simple.
Is it a good idea ?
Where would it store the data on the android device ?
How would you do it ?

I didn't try it yet. The alternative would be to implement myself a synchronization mechanism, using `REST` requests to the `couchdb` server, storing the data in some local DB like hive. But in my experience, it can easily get messy when the network isn't reliable.

Comment: Wouldn't couchbase lite be easier? https://pub.dev/packages/cbl_flutter

Comment: couchbase isn't compatible with couchdb, it's a different project